# Serialize EntitySet<T> c#

Tags: c#, linq, serialization

I would like some help with a c# issue. I have a customer class which has an `EntitySet<Book>`.
The class is marked `Serializable` so that I can serialize it with a `BinaryFormatter`. The problem is that the `EntitySet` is not serializable.

I need to serialize it manually with a `MemoryStream`. Does anyone know how to achieve this? A code sample would be great!

Comment: why don't you use another collection type?

Comment: I dearly miss the "minimal understanding" close reason for XY problems. You shouldn't want to do what you're trying to do (it makes as much sense as wanting to serialize a socket). Explain _why_ you think you need to serialize it as `EntitySet<T>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by using a surrogate serializer: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188950.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Via the use of reflection you can step over the public and private fields as well as the class name and the parent you inherit from of the instantiated object.

Output these values to a string save it to a memorystream which you can read from later and then create a new object with reflection based on the type found.

Currently unable to give a more clear example. But this is one of the many ways to go